# Android Studio 3.6 my layout content goes down

Tags: android, kotlin

After updating Android Studio to the latest version if i create a new app and but simple textview to that app the textview goes at the center of the layout instead of the top, i don't know what's wrong please help me.

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="My name is john"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to where you placed your `fragment` or `BottomNavigationView`, most of the time it located in `activity_main`, So remove this `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to the parent layout